# Random Poisson Sum of Random Variables with known distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, random-variables

I am trying to get a closed form expression for the expected value of the following summation of RVs: $\sum_{i=1}^{Y} X_{i}$, where $Y$ is Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda$ and $ X_{i} $ follows some known distribution $f_X(x)$. Are there any means to drop the RV $Y$ using $\lambda$?

Thank you for your time and patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if your $X_i$'s are iid, then you can use iterated conditioning to prove the Wald's identity.

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_X[\sum_{i=1}^Y X_i] &= \mathbb{E}_Y[\mathbb{E}_X[\sum_{i=1}^y X_i | Y=y]]\\
&=\mathbb{E}_Y[ y \mathbb{E}_X[X_1]]\\
&= \sum_{y=0}^{\infty} y \mathbb{E}_X[X_1] e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^y}{y !}\\
&= \lambda \mathbb{E}[X_1] e^{-\lambda} \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\lambda^{y-1}}{(y-1) !}\\
&= \lambda \mathbb{E}X_1
\end{align}

since the sum is an series expansion for $e^{\lambda}$. We're using the iid property to go from the first to the second line. Then it's just the expectation of the Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If the $X_i$'s are independent then
$$ \mathbb E \left[ \sum_{i=1}^Y X_i \right] = \mathbb E(Y) \mathbb E(X_1) = \lambda \mathbb E(X_1),  $$
assuming that $\mathbb E(X_1)$ exists. It's Wald's identity.

Comment: Beat me to it!  Good answer though.

Comment: I have a doubt now. Is the independence of $Y$ and the $X_i$'s necessary?

Comment: My recollection is that finite means are all that are required.  Ask a RNG for a value of Y and fix it first.  It shouldn't matter if that result depends on the $X$ values or not, you'll be summing up that many expectations.  I initially read your answer as having independent $X$ values, not $X$ and $Y$.  But I don't think $Y$ has to be independent of $X_i$ for that identity to apply.

Comment: OK thanks. I edit.